# How to fix kafka SCRAM authentication failure

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

version of confluent platform: **5.4.1**
I followed the document and previous question to setup the SCRAM authentication:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_scram.html#
- [kafka SASL/SCRAM Failed authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594103/kafka-sasl-scram-failed-authentication)

After I modified my configurations, the SASL authentication of zookeeper server is successful but the kafka server is still failed. the below shows the log messages and my related configuration, please help advise on it

**zookeeper server output:**

```
[2020-07-18 23:53:42,917] INFO Successfully authenticated client: authenticationID=adminuser;  authorizationID=adminuser. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SaslServerCallbackHandler)
[2020-07-18 23:53:43,143] INFO Setting authorizedID: adminuser (org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SaslServerCallbackHandler)
[2020-07-18 23:53:43,143] INFO adding SASL authorization for authorizationID: adminuser (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2020-07-18 23:53:51,162] INFO Successfully authenticated client: authenticationID=adminuser;  authorizationID=adminuser. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SaslServerCallbackHandler)
[2020-07-18 23:53:51,162] INFO Setting authorizedID: adminuser (org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SaslServerCallbackHandler)
[2020-07-18 23:53:51,162] INFO adding SASL authorization for authorizationID: adminuser (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
```

**kafka server error message:**

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException: Cancelled fetchMetadata request with correlation id 11 due to node -1 being disconnected
[2020-07-19 00:23:59,921] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /192.168.20.10 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2020-07-19 00:24:00,095] WARN [Producer clientId=confluent-metrics-reporter] Bootstrap broker 192.168.20.10:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-07-19 00:24:00,403] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /192.168.20.10 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2020-07-19 00:24:00,597] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /192.168.20.10 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
[2020-07-19 00:24:00,805] INFO [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with /192.168.20.10 (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

**zookeeper_server_jaas.conf:**

```
Server {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    user_adminuser="adminuserpwd";
};
```

**zookeeper.properties:**

```
server.001=192.168.20.10:2888:3888
authProvider.001=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
```

**zookeeper-server-start:**

```
...
export ZK_AUTH_ARGS=$base_dir/../data/zookeeper_server_jaas.conf
exec $base_dir/kafka-run-class $EXTRA_ARGS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$ZK_AUTH_ARGS  org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "$@"
```

**Added user:**

```
bin/kafka-configs --zookeeper 192.168.20.10:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[password=adminuserpwd],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=adminuserpwd]' --entity-type users --entity-name adminuser

bin/kafka-configs --zookeeper 192.168.20.10:2181 --describe --entity-type users --entity-name adminuser

Configs for user-principal 'adminuser' are SCRAM-SHA-512=salt=MTdxamZocWJlY2F2dDFhZGc0dmluZm5hcmo=,stored_key=o21ptVzTVZoR/hafmOgTSYmr2F1TORPo6xDaZGAph+6OncE1pw/AyLRwduCx0Qx97bKoPWmlYShfXtbug6u8kg==,server_key=1B/1/CzPTpMBO9MpfKZb504JFLZUia0D6LatAllSYkrTa8XWbaISDGQ29Yf4UU+jQmo+iQgK0jX+KaV+fUV6XA==,iterations=4096,SCRAM-SHA-256=salt=MWlrZGs5dHd4dDhiZmdqZGxnN2cwOGpuaGs=,stored_key=vSJ83eDvilj4JyQyehPaGmG3EZISRRfo3j8iY8uiWLU=,server_key=Bu/KfHnv6bSay/n4dO/h55O9WLLaAjiLtJQzfpr4cs0=,iterations=4096
```

**kafka_server_jaas.conf:**

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
    username="adminuser"
    password="adminuserpwd";
};
Client {
    org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
    username="adminuser"
    password="adminuserpwd";
};
```

**kafka server.properties:**

```
...
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.20.10:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://192.168.20.10:9092
zookeeper.connect=192.168.20.10:2181
authorizer.class.name=io.confluent.kafka.security.authorizer.ConfluentServerAuthorizer
super.users=User:adminuser
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
...
```

**kafka-server-start:**

```
...
KAFKA_AUTH_ARGS=$base_dir/../data/kafka_server_jaas.conf
exec $base_dir/kafka-run-class $EXTRA_ARGS -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$KAFKA_AUTH_ARGS io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka "$@"
```